# Dropbox file link for embedding in iframe

Tags: dropbox

I want to allow my users to import file from dropbox and show them in iframe. Using chooser dropin, I can get the share link, but it's not iframable due to 'X-Frame-ORIGIN' header. I don't want the raw file content as I can't convert it to html and show in browser. Is there some url where I get dropbox preview url which is iframable as well.

From some blogs I gathered that changing host in url to dl.dropboxusercontent.com and adding dl=0 parameter we could get a iframable preview url. But this no longer works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropbox site at www.dropbox.com doesn't allow iframing, but dl.dropboxusercontent.com does. However, the "preview" is only available on www.dropbox.com, so unfortunately you can't iframe the preview.

The official information about the different parameters you can use is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Comment: that's really surprising. Google drive, box, OneDrive all provide a embed url for shared files. I am now thinking of using this api: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#previews as a workaround

Comment: I believe the restriction on iframing www.dropbox.com itself is a security precaution, but using the /previews functionality in the API is a great solution if it fits your use case.

Answer (score 7):

A simple way of doing it is to ensure that the link sharing mode is set to available with the link, copy the link into your iframe src and then change the `dl=0` bit to `raw=1` so that it looks like:

```
www.dropbox.com/s/<FILEID>/file?raw=1
```

Comment: Google Chrome downloads the file when I use this url structure in an iframe.

Comment: How does one identify the file ID?